# Correcting 100% width with anchors adding in padding

Tags: css

Ok, so I have a class that modifies the looks for a specific type of anchor that I'm using, but the problem is that the browsers keep adding the 30 pixels of padding that I have set onto the defined 100% width, so it's stretching out past the box which the anchor is located in.

```css
div.box div div div a.option_line {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-weight: normal;
    min-height: 30px;
    padding: 0px 10px 0px 20px;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Can anyone think of a way to make the anchor stay within the boundaries of the box?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just take out the `width: 100%`, as the `a` is declared to be a block level element, it will stretch to the maximum width available without going over.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the width:100%; that caused the issue, since you already set the display to 'block' the width:100% isn't necessary because block elements occupies the available width of the container